# 2 dimensional packing Problem with flexible objects

Tags: algorithms, discrete-optimization, packing-problem

I have a kind of bin packing problem defined as follows:
given: m bins $b_1,...,b_m$ of height $h_1,....,h_m$ and width w.
The packing objects simply map $1,...,w$ to integers, hence these are
functions  $p_i$ with $0<i<n+1$. If $x_{ij}$ is a binary variable indicating that object
i is assigned to bin j, then it must hold for all bins $b_j$ and all 
$0<k<w+1$ that
$$\sum_{0<i<n+1} x_{ij} p_i(k) \le h_j.$$

The goal is to pack all the objects into the bins.
One can assume that any $p_i$ does not have 'zero gaps' if we plot 
the function Graph with $1,...,w$ on the x-axis.

Any help in pointing towards the right papers and algorithms  is
appreciated.

Thanks Daniel

Comment: I found out that it has a close relationship to MULTIDIMENSIONAL MULTI-WAY NUMBER PARTIONING. For this Problem there are many papers on Heuristic algorithms.